# Error when compiling a cydia tweak GPUImage

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos, tweak

I am writing a tweak that requires GPUImage framework but I am not sure how to install it. Do I just copy all the headers to theos/include folder? (in this case i am getting "undefined symbols for architecture armv7"error when compiling. I do have "export ARCHS = armv7 armv7s arm64" inside of my makefile.

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using xcode, which was giving the same error but then solved by #importing QuartzCore.h and AVFoundation.h.